# Cisco 4200 WLC management ports down

Tags: cisco

I hope this is a simple problem, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

I went through the CLI setup for my Cisco 4200 WLC, and configured the management interface, and the ap-manager interface to be on my LAN. Double checked the settings through the Web GUI and it all looks right. The thing is, I connected the WLC into a switch with a clean config, and connected the switch to my LAN. Nothing. The web client still says the status of both ports is "link down", and there are no lights on the appliance indicating otherwise.

The RJ-45 adapter (model GLC-T) connected to the management port I'm using is functional - I tested it on an open spot on the switch. So that's not the issue.

Full disclosure, I got the WLC on ebay a while back and am just now getting around to figuring it out. So I'm not sure if there's an issue with the appliance or not, but it appears to function normally otherwise.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the switch connected to the distribution port has to be connected to a gig port, the 10mpbs and 100mbps ports standart on most Cisco switches won't work. Plugged into a gig port and it worked like a charm.